# Ionic - Show initially hidden divs on clicking an option from dropdown

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

If I click on option 1 from dropdown list, a div which is initially hidden should be displayed. And if I click on another option from same dropdown list different div should be displayed and previous div should be hidden. I don't want to use JQuery as I have very less knowledge about it but only AngularJs.

My code is:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="item item-divider" align="center">
    Candidates
</div>
<div class="padding">   
<div class="form-group" align="center">
    <label for="sel1"></label>
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
            <option>Location 1</option>
            <option>Location 2</option>
            <option>Location 3</option>
        </select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Working example
http://plnkr.co/edit/SKdeAHMmvFB85ym1hfGr?p=preview

You can use `ng-model` to do this

```
<select ng-model="location.type" class="form-control" id="sel1" ng-change="changeme()">
    <option ng-option value="1">Location 1</option>
    <option ng-option value="2">Location 2</option>
    <option ng-option value="3">Location 3</option>
  </select>

  <div ng-if="location.type == '1'">Location 1</div>
  <div ng-if="location.type == '2'">Location 2</div>
  <div ng-if="location.type == '3'">Location 3</div>
```

There's only one problem, and that's that empty option at the start. Once changed it's gone.

Comment: worked.. thanx a lot.. but would you mind me explaining the flow of how this thing worked?

Comment: The `ng-model` will look for the value of the selected option. You can then use it to check your divs if the value is the same with an `ng-if`. The value can be anything like 'banana' but then you'll have to change the `ng-if`to `ng-if="location.type == 'banana'"` . Hopefully this clears it up